# Getting buildings multipatch from LiDAR data without building footprints?

Tags: arcgis-pro, lidar, 3d, multipatch, building-heights

I have a 3D LiDAR data and aerial images.

Is there a way to obtain the buildings multipatch (.shp), given that I don't actually have the buildings' footprints?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being an online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Does your LIDAR data includes the buildings? If so, I think you can filter the points above, for example a specific height, and from then you can interpolate the points. But before that, have you take a look if your area is covered by OpenStreetMap buildings? Take a look at this references: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/downloading_osm_data.html
https://github.com/tudelft3d/3dfier/wiki/Extracting-building-footprints-from-OpenStreetMap
https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this in ArcGIS Pro is outlined in the [Extract Roof Forms for Municipal Development](https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/extract-roof-forms-for-municipal-development/) tutorial where:

> Your goal is to create a 3D scene of an area in Portland with LOD 2
>   buildings. With the aid of an ArcGIS Pro task, you'll create a point
>   cloud dataset derived from lidar data and use it to make digital
>   elevation models of the area. Using tools that analyze patterns in the
>   elevation models, you'll add roof form attribute data to building
>   footprints and symbolize the footprints in 3D. Lastly, you'll review
>   the data and edit building features to fix errors before converting
>   the data to a multipatch feature class that you can easily share with
>   the municipal government.